# iOS Bounds of UIView in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, null, viewdidload, bounds

I wanted to use the bounds of a UIView to create a UILabel and add it to that UIView inside the viewDidLoad method, however, I have found that the bounds of UIView is still null inside viewDidLoad. But when I look at a demo app, the bounds of its UIView is already initialised in viewDidLoad.

In the interface I have

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *promotionView;
@end
```

And I am trying to do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.promotionView.bounds];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, container.bounds.size.height-100, 320, 20)];
    label.text = @"Promotion Title";
    [container addSubview:label];
    [self.promotionView addSubview: container];
}
```

but it doesn't work because the bounds of promotionView is null.

Comment: Change this code to `viewWillAppear` also check the outlet is connected

Comment: The bounds of `promotionView` are not `nil`. It is `promotionView` itself that is `nil`. Make sure you are actually setting `promotionView` to the proper view.

Comment: @MidhunMP Putting such code in `viewWillAppear` is not appropriate. `viewWillAppear` can be called many times if other view controllers are pushed/pop from the nav stack.

Comment: @rmaddy I have created the UIView inside the storyboard and linked it to the view controller, do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and run the app with the debugger. When you get to the breakpoint, check to see if `promotionView` is `nil` or not.

Comment: @rmaddy, self.view's bounds is not 0 in viewDidLoad, but the bounds of a subview of self.view is.

Comment: For the 3rd time - check to see if `promotionView` is `nil` or not. Don't check the bounds, don't check `self.view`, check `promotionView`.

Comment: @rmaddy I got promotionViews=(NSMutableArray *) 0x00000000, not sure if this is nil or not

Comment: Yes, that's `nil`. You are never setting or connection or whatever any view to the `self.promotionView` outlet.

Comment: First, you need to resolve whether your view is nil. Did you log promotionView or promotionViews? The latter is an array, not a view.

Comment: @rdelmar I log promotionView and this is what I got <UIView: 0x715d5d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x76789a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x715d680>>

Comment: Ok, so your view isn't nil. You need to put the code you posted in viewDidAppear. You'll need to put some logic in there so that code is only called the first time viewDidAppear runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in viewDidAppear:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static int first = 1;
    if (first) {
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.promotionView.bounds];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, container.bounds.size.height-100, 320, 20)];
        label.text = @"Promotion Title";
        [container addSubview:label];
        [self.promotionView addSubview: container];
        first = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, but I'm still curious as to why my UIView bound is 0 in viewDidLoad while the demo code can use it. I am using demo code from here btw [link](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController)

Comment: @doog, it looks like he's using self.view.frame in that demo -- the controller's self.view is not nil at the time of viewDidLoad, but your added subviews are.

Comment: @doog, I should qualify my comment about a subview's bounds being 0 in viewDidLoad -- this is true when auto layout is turned on (which it is by default), but it will have the bounds you set in the storyboard if auto layout is turned off. I always leave it on, but then do any sizing of views using constraints rather than setting frames.